# ParquetAvroWriters missing parquet avro dependences

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro, parquet

I'm trying to follow the StreamingFileSink tutorial from Stream Processing with Apache Flink.

The books mentions that I can specific my AvroPOJO object and save my stream to a parquet file with avro schema into my local fs.

It looks like this:

```scala
val sink: StreamingFileSink[String] = StreamingFileSink
  .forBulkFormat(
    new Path("/base/path"), 
    ParquetAvroWriters.forSpecificRecord(classOf[AvroPojo]))
  .build()
```

After I added(tested both 1.9 and 1.8 and in 1.9 I used flink-parquet_2.11)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-parquet</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then I can successfully use ParquetAvroWriter but compile with missing ParquetAvroWriter error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/formats/parquet/avro/ParquetAvroWriters
```

So I have to add **parquet-avro** dependence manuelly.

Then it just give me:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

Update:

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.compat}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.compat}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime-web_${scala.compat}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-parquet_${scala.compat}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pulsar/pulsar-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
            <artifactId>pulsar-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Question
1. How can I compile this code and without config hadoop? Or any other way to persist the data in my local fs with parquet and avro?

Comment: can you post the dependency's file .
im assuming that something is missing

Comment: @MIkCode updated, and it's compiled after I added the hadoop-client and no idea why. Streaming process seem working now but the reuslt are not persisted on my local disk